# setinterval keeps running after ajax load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I load content in to a DIV (#mydiv) from a page (mypage.php) . The page that i get content from has javascript inside.

In THE mypage.php

```
 function refresh_feeds() {
//bla bla
}

$(function(){

    feed_timer = setInterval(refresh_feeds, 50000);

});
```

When i clean the content of #mydiv and load content from another page (mypage2.php), setInterval that started in mypage.php keeps running.

my question is how can i stop it when the content from mypage.php is unloaded

or

how can i handle unload event of mypage.php ?

Comment: I did not understand what you are doing but I think `clearTimeout(feed_timer);` will help you. Just execute it when you load the content from mypage2.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function refresh_feeds() {
  console.log(1);
}

$(function() {
  window.feed_timer = window.setInterval(refresh_feeds, 100);
});

$(window).bind("beforeunload",function() {
  window.clearInterval(window.feed_timer);
  window.feed_timer = null;
  return 1;
});
```

Please check in console for this

Comment: console keeps logging 1 even if it unloads the content : ( it seems beforeunload binding doesnt work if it is loaded dynamically

Comment: Copy that code and open console in this page, paste there and refresh the page, you'll get two options like confirm(), You can see the refresh_feeds() is not called further!

Answer (score 1):

```
var feed_timer;
function refresh_feeds() {
    //bla bla
}

$(function(){
    clearInterval(feed_timer);
    feed_timer = setInterval(refresh_feeds, 50000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to clear your Interval

```
clearInterval(feed_timer);
```

be sure to save the feed_timer in a global scope